# How do I wait for a handle to be created for a comboBox, so that I can change the selectedIndex?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm stuck on this problem with a `ComboBox`.

I need to create it programmatically, set a `DataSource`, add it to my form and then change the `SelectedIndex`. I'm doing it like this:

```
rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height)
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox
                        {
                            Size = Rectangle.Size,
                            Location = Rectangle.Location,
                            DataSource = new List<string>(comboBoxDataSource),
                        };
Form1.Controls.Add(cb);
cb.SelectedIndex = index;
```

When the program gets to that last line, i throws an error saying:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'InvalidArgument=Value of '4' is
>   not valid for 'SelectedIndex'. Parameter name: SelectedIndex'

When the code crash I can see that the `ComboBox` contains 6 items, so shouldn't index '4' be valid at this point?

I have read some articles and other questions about the problem, but nothing I have found have worked. I think it's because the form doesn't create a handle for the `ComboBox`, before I try to change the index.

Is there anyone who have had a similar problem, or know a solution?

Comment: Add more information. What is `comboBoxDataSource` and why are you adding it as List initializer parameter instead of using `comboBoxDataSource` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the datasource after you add your combobox to the control. Then you can select an item.

```
        var dataSource = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };

        var rectangle = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 40);
        ComboBox cb = new ComboBox
        {
            Location = rectangle.Location,
            Size = rectangle.Size,
        };
        this.Controls.Add(cb);

        cb.DataSource = new List<string>(dataSource);
        cb.SelectedIndex = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `BindingSource` and set its `DataSource`. Add a binding context to the combobox and after that set the combobox `DataSource` to the `BindingSource.DataSource`. See below:

```
string[] dataSource = new string[30];
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    dataSource[i] = "test " + i.ToString();
}
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
cb.Size = new Size(121, 21);
cb.Location = new Point(55, 74);
BindingSource bS = new BindingSource();
cb.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
bS.DataSource = dataSource;
cb.DataSource = bS.DataSource;
cb.SelectedIndex = 4; // shoul and does display test 3
this.Controls.Add(cb);
```